# In VS code need to perform open with live server every time to see changes done in code on web browser

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have installed extension called live server in vs code, So that Till yesterday I could open my HTML file on browser directly from VS code through open with live server option , and if I performed any changes to code browser get automatically reloaded with new changes.
But now I need to always select open with live server option to see effects of updated code in my browser. Browser not automatically reloaded, manually reloading also doesn't have any effect.
Any buddy know solution please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Watch this video it explains clearly https://youtu.be/wMmu_369n7c, Other wise install extension called SaveTyping by Michel Betancourt.

Comment: it is better to Explain the solution